# Update fullcalendar with array

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

I try to create scenarios containing multiple events, then drag and drop these scenarios on my calendar. The problem is that the scenario can not be duplicated on another day. When I slide a new scenario, everything disappears.

Have you any idea?

http://jsfiddle.net/spitfire378/YLEmN/

Maybe a problem with the :

```
addEventSource render.
```

thx a lot

Comment: Maybe an duplicated id for a scenario?!?

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to come from an array of objects. In the initial example:http://arshaw.com/js/fullcalendar-1.6.4/demos/external-dragging.html
It uses the extend function to duplicate the object. But in my case I use an array of objects. There he has a way to duplicate my array of objects?

Thx a lot